# why my form method post not working

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a problem with my form.the method="post" did not working.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Choose your Package</label>
<select id="pckgeID" name="pckgeID" class="form-control">
<option value="1">Package A</option>
<option value="2">Package B</option>
<option value="3">Package C</option>
</select>
<label>Condition</label>
<select id="condition" name="condition" class="form-control">
<option value="fragile">Fragile(handle with care)</option>
<option value="not fragile">Not Fragile</option>
</select>
<input class="btn btn-default pad" style="float:right;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i tried to do

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit')
{   

echo 'successful';                      

header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
}
?>
```

but it didnt echo anything.my other form is working just fine so i dont get it why this one isnt working.please help me.

Comment: `<input class="btn btn-default pad" style="float:right;" type="submit" ` has no name so `$_POST['submit']` is never set. Your html is invalid by the way.

Comment: i already put name=submit value=Submit.

Comment: you might want to edit your question then to help get quality answers

Comment: @Calimero: scroll to the right. it's there, there's just a bunch of extract space in the submit tag.

Comment: @AshrafKamarudin: basic debugging: put in `var_dump($_POST);`  and see what's being received by the server.

Comment: put it below isset($post ? it shows nothing

Comment: can you comment `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;` lines and then try @AshrafKamarudin

Comment: array(3) { ["pckgeID"]=> string(1) "2" ["condition"]=> string(11) "not fragile" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } successful i got this.does this mean its working?

Comment: I think yes. Thing is that at the beging it was working but you have header lines that basicly was redirecting you to referer page and refer page is same just without posted values and this is why you never got succesful echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently i was redirecting the page to referer page and referer page is same. just without posted values. thanks for @standej for pointing it out